# How to learn the Clojure way on my own?

Tags: clojure, idioms

I'm learning Clojure using tutorials and going through problems like [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/) and [99 lisp problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html). I do fine with solving problems, but my code always seem to come out to be a mess like the example below.

For a language as flexible as Clojure, how can a beginner learn the idiomatic ways without having somebody else hand holding along the way?

An example of my mess:

```
(defn intersectall [lset] 
  (when-not (empty? (first lset))
    (if (reduce #(and %1 %2) (map #(stars/member* (front lset) %) (rest lset)))
        (cons (front lset) (intersectall (cons (rest (first lset)) (rest lset))))
        (intersectall (cons (rest (first lset)) (rest lset))))))
```

In case you're wondering, the function `intersectall` merely returns a list of the common elements in all sub-lists of input.

So for:

```
(def lset '((6 :pears :and)
        (3 :peaches :and 6 :peppers)
            (8 :pears :and 6 :plums)
        (:and 6 :prunes :with some :apples)))

=> (intersectall lset)
(6 :and)
```

This problem is from The Little Schemer pg 117.

Comment: You should post this kind of questions at the [Google Group of Clojure](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure?pli=1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to GET Clojure, I strongly recommend [The Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/) book. It is written by two of the guys who know the language best next to the original creator. They explain what you can do, how you should do it, and then the whys. I don't think it is a good FIRST book/learning experience on the language, however I think it is the required SECOND book to study from once you have your fundamentals.

Comment: @stand: if you are requesting I add my third, none of the currently available clojure books make a good one, though I'm anxious to get my hands on Clojure Programming and see how that fits in with the rest. Personally after JoC I'd go to the mailing list and the IRC channel on freenode.

Comment: sorry I was unclear. I meant that after you read JoC as your second book, you should read it again as your third.

Comment: And is there a good first book / tutorial that you would recommend now a few years later ?

Answer (score 4):

Both writing and reading code are appropriate and necessary. If the Clojure source code seems intimidating, start with smaller projects, e.g., https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke. Since you have been doing the 4Clojure problems, why not look at others' solutions after you have written your own? Search for the hashtag #4clojure in twitter or just visit https://twitter.com/#!/search/%234clojure.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree -- a key learning aspect of 4Clojure is reviewing other's answers.  

You can find all levels of solution quality from ones that are clearly just an imperative solution wrapped with parens to ones that are so short and concise that you spend days working out just how the are done so elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract your code into smaller functions that do one thing and one thing well. Once you have achieved this you can try to make it more elegant. Sometimes you notice your final result is so sweet and short you actually end up inlining it.

Bind the values you have already obtained by using `let`. For instance calling `(first lset)` several times in several different places makes your code more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Read code. Read well written code.

You could start with clojure's source - get it here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src/clj/clojure. Usually the code in the standard-lib of a language is/has to be quite idiomatic. So this is a good place to start your journey.

Comment: You're really going to tell a beginner in programming to start with Clojure's source?

Comment: Do *not* read clojure.core for inspiration. The other packages might be okay, but core is very performance-centric and is busy bootstrapping by defining the whole standard library in terms of the compiler primitives.

Comment: I agree clojure.core can be quite tricky in places - but I personally found it fairly helpful when learning Clojure. YMMV here I think - certainly worth a browse for those beginners who are interested in how the internals work.

Comment: I think to get at a large body of source fast clojure's source, standard lib and clojure.contrib are a good entry-point. They will at least give you a feel for the language.
I don't think this is a good starting point for beginning programming in general, though.

Comment: Once you have a good foundation Clojure core and similar are great place to get deeper appreciation, but only after you really know what you are doing. Contrib should have some good examples sprinkled throughout, though haven't spelunked it in a while so couldn't tell you current good examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest deconstructing a complex example. At the Denver Clojure Meetup, we deconstructed the *Joy of Clojure* Quicksort listing 6.3 line by line. I have the slides [here](https://github.com/julienchastang/meetup-5-18-2011).